# Digital audio workstation - software available and running on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-recommendation, audio-recording

I am planning to buy a Focusrite scarlett 2i2 sound card and I am wondering if there is any Digital audio workstation running properly in Ubuntu, any suggestions will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try out audio workstation packages on [Ubuntu Studio](http://ubuntustudio.org/tour/audio/)

Can also add the Ubuntu Studio packages to any other version of Ubuntu